# open external links in new tab, embeded in fancybox popup

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I am trying to manipulate the following code to open a link in a new tab. Which is embeded in fancybox 1.3.4 popup.  The issue is adding target="_blank" and onclick function gets ignored and causes the link to open in the parent page. I have also tried using javascript void (0) target"_blank" and have managed to leave the page in a new tab however the new page is blank when it appears.

this is the line of the code I am trying to manipulate to leave fancybox and open in a new tab:

```
$link = ($attachment_meta)? "<a href='$attachment_meta'>$image</a>" : $image;

ex: $link = ($attachment_meta)? "<a href='$attachment_meta'
target'_blank'>$image</a>" : $image; <-- adding target_blank in code
does not work!--
```

This is a snippet of the code:

```
if( 'custom' == $attr['link']){
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false);
      $attachment_meta = get_post_meta($id, '_rt-image-link', true);
 $link = ($attachment_meta)? "<a href='$attachment_meta'>$image</a>" : $image;
} else {
      $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
  }

      $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
     $output .= "
<{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
$link
</{$icontag}>";
     if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
     $output .= "
<{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
" . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
</{$captiontag}>";
     }
     $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
     if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
     $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';

}
```

Comment: What does your rendered html look like?

Comment: <?php if ( gallery_shortcode( $post->ID ) ){?>
<div id="demo-accordion" data-role="z-accordion" data-options='{"theme": "red", "active": 0, "sectionSpacing": 4}'>
    <section>
        <h3>Get the look!</h3>
        <div><?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');?></div>
    </section>
</div>
<?php } ?> <-- this is a snippet of the html code which calls on gallery which shows in fancybox popup.. I am trying to manipulate the gallery links to leave fancybox when the gallery image is clicked on.

Comment: Can we see what HTML the browser gets (not the php code that produces it) Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on this code in a local environment.